# How to specify the image scaling algorithm used by a WPF Image?

Tags: wpf, image-scaling

Is there a way to specify how an image is scaled up in an `Image` element with `LayoutTransform` set to a `ScaleTransform` with integer values for `ScaleX` and `ScaleY`?

I want to display the scaled image crisply (ie using 'nearest neighbour' scaling), with no blurring. (Imagine how you would want a bitmap editing program to behave when zooming in).

I noticed the protected property `VisualBitmapScalingMode` on `Image`, so created a subclass of `Image` that sets this property to `BitmapScalingMode.NearestNeighbor`. However, this had no effect.

Comment: Your subclass won't change how the ScaleTransform works, I think.  Have you tried setting the image size manually (width/height) to see if it is crisp?

Comment: Unfortunately not. If I expand the Image by setting Width and Height I get the same result as applying a ScaleTransform. Which makes sense I think, given that either way, it's ultimately the Image that decides how to render itself given a size, and a bitmap.

Comment: Have you gotten any better results with the TransformedBitmap?

Comment: OK if I override OnRender on Image, perhaps I can specify the scaling algorithm to use in the DrawingContext somehow...

Comment: OK, got it working. Although I was setting the value of VisualBitmapScalingMode in the constructor of 'MyImage' (my Image subclass), it was set back to Unspecified by the time OnRender was called. So, I override OnRender, and set it there, then call base.OnRender. Maybe there is some override in the lifecycle of a WPF element where I could set this property once, but job done.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I fixed this by overriding OnRender in my Image subclass, and setting the VisualBitmapScalingMode before drawing the image:

```
class MyImage : System.Windows.Controls.Image
  {
    protected override void OnRender(DrawingContext dc)
    {
      this.VisualBitmapScalingMode = System.Windows.Media.BitmapScalingMode.NearestNeighbor;
      base.OnRender(dc);
    }
  }
```

Comment: This works great. I used it for the opposite effect (i.e. Fant method), but got exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 10):

You can set the [RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.renderoptions.bitmapscalingmode(v=vs.110).aspx) property in the XAML for the Image control. There's no need to inherit the Image class.

Comment: I have a zoom control that changes transform of the child, the image inside the child is blurry even with NearestNeighbor mode. OnRender solution worked (WPF 4.6.2)