# TransformedBitmap Scaling Mode

Tags: c#, wpf, image, scaling

I'm using a `TransformedBitmap` class to draw scaled images to a `Bitmap` using `TransformedBitmap.CopyPixels`. Is there a way to specify the scaling mode that is used? `RenderOptions.SetBitmapScalingMode` doesn't seem to affect anything. I would like to use nearest neighbor but it appears to use a bi linear filter of some sort.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- It is not possible to specify the scaling algorithm, it is by design.
- The RenderOptions.SetBitmapScalingMode applies to rendering only, e.g. you have a 32*32 icon and want to show it at 256*256 but still in a blocky way (nearest neighbour)

**Update**

A few ways on how you could overcome this issue :

Do it by yourself :
http://tech-algorithm.com/articles/nearest-neighbor-image-scaling/

Using Forms :
https://stackoverflow.com/a/1856362/361899

Custom drawing :
[How to specify the image scaling algorithm used by a WPF Image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2913060/how-to-specify-the-image-scaling-algorithm-used-by-a-wpf-image)

There is AForge too but that might be overkill for your needs.

**Update 2**

WriteableBitmapEx will probably do the job easily for you : http://writeablebitmapex.codeplex.com/

You can resize a WriteableBitmap, specify interpolation mode and there is nearest neighbor.

Both TransformedBitmap and WriteableBitmapEx inherit from BitmapSource, likely you'll have no change to make at all to your existing code.

Comment: Interesting, do you have any suggestions for an alternative? (Given that I have a bitmapsource which needs to be scaled and copied to a Bitmap)

Comment: I've added a few ways for you in my answer. (sorry but I'm on my phone and it's not very practical)

Comment: The WriteableBitmapEx looks like the thing to use, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

```
 public static class Extensions
{
    public static BitmapFrame Resize(this
BitmapSource photo, int width, int height,
BitmapScalingMode scalingMode)
    {

        var group = new DrawingGroup();
        RenderOptions.SetBitmapScalingMode(
            group, scalingMode);
        group.Children.Add(
            new ImageDrawing(photo,
                new Rect(0, 0, width, height)));
        var targetVisual = new DrawingVisual();
        var targetContext = targetVisual.RenderOpen();
        targetContext.DrawDrawing(group);
        var target = new RenderTargetBitmap(
            width, height, 96, 96, PixelFormats.Default);
        targetContext.Close();
        target.Render(targetVisual);
        var targetFrame = BitmapFrame.Create(target);
        return targetFrame;
    }
}
```

Took from http://weblogs.asp.net/bleroy/resizing-images-from-the-server-using-wpf-wic-instead-of-gdi