# WPF Zoom Canvas Center on Mouse Position

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, mvvm-light

```
<utils:ScrollViewer x:Name="ImageViewer" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Grid.Row="2"                                                                   
                                       CurrentHorizontalOffset="{Binding ScrollHorizontalValue, Mode=TwoWay}"
                                       CurrentVerticalOffset="{Binding ScrollVerticalValue, Mode=TwoWay}"                                        
                                       >
                    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                        <i:EventTrigger EventName="PreviewMouseWheel">
                            <cmd:EventToCommand Command="{Binding MouseWheelZoomCommand}" PassEventArgsToCommand="True"/>
                        </i:EventTrigger>
                        <i:EventTrigger EventName="ScrollChanged">
                            <cmd:EventToCommand Command="{Binding ScrollChangedCommand}" PassEventArgsToCommand="True"/>
                        </i:EventTrigger>
                    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
                    <Grid Background="{StaticResource ThatchBackground}" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
                        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding CanvasItems}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource templateOfROI}">
                            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                    <Canvas x:Name="BackPanel"
                                        Width="{Binding DataContext.ImageWidth, ElementName=MainGrid}" 
                                        Height="{Binding DataContext.ImageHeight, ElementName=MainGrid}"
                                        ClipToBounds="True">
                                        <Canvas.Background>
                                            <ImageBrush x:Name="BackImage"
                                                        ImageSource="{Binding DataContext.SelectedImage.Path, ElementName=MainGrid}"/>
                                        </Canvas.Background>

                                        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                                            <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseRightButtonDown">
                                                <cmd:EventToCommand Command="{Binding DataContext.MouseRightCommand, ElementName=MainGrid}"/>
                                            </i:EventTrigger>
                                            <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseLeftButtonDown">
                                                <cmd:EventToCommand Command="{Binding DataContext.MouseMoveStartCommand, ElementName=MainGrid}" PassEventArgsToCommand="True"/>
                                            </i:EventTrigger>
                                            <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseMove">
                                                <cmd:EventToCommand Command="{Binding DataContext.MouseMovingCommand, ElementName=MainGrid}" PassEventArgsToCommand="True"/>
                                            </i:EventTrigger>
                                            <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseRightButtonUp">
                                                <cmd:EventToCommand Command="{Binding DataContext.MouseMoveEndCommand, ElementName=MainGrid}"/>
                                            </i:EventTrigger>
                                            <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseLeave">
                                                <cmd:EventToCommand Command="{Binding DataContext.MouseLeaveCommand, ElementName=MainGrid}"/>
                                            </i:EventTrigger>
                                        </i:Interaction.Triggers>

                                        <Canvas.LayoutTransform>
                                            <TransformGroup>
                                                <ScaleTransform ScaleX="{Binding ScaleX}"
                                                                ScaleY="{Binding ScaleY}">
                                                </ScaleTransform>
                                        </TransformGroup>
                                    </Canvas.LayoutTransform>
                                </Canvas>
                            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                    </ItemsControl>
                </Grid>
            </utils:ScrollViewer>
```

The reference point is fixed with Left and Top points to zoom the Canvas. I'd like to zoom in and zoom out on the mouse pointer. How do I make it into the MVVM Pattern? (Not Behind code). Using mouse wheel, I can zoom in canvas. I already use RenderTransformOrigin, CenterX, CenterY but it is not worked. I think I made a wrong approach. Please help me..

Comment: Where is your code that handles the zooming? Even when it's not working as expected, you should still include it as your current approach.

Answer (score 16):

Since you didn't provide your current zooming code, here is a generic example of zooming on the mouse position:

```
<Grid x:Name="grid1" Background="White" MouseWheel="Grid_MouseWheel">
    <Grid x:Name="grid2">
        <Grid.RenderTransform>
            <MatrixTransform/>
        </Grid.RenderTransform>
        <Rectangle Width="20" Height="20" Margin="20" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Fill="Green"/>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

With code that updates the transformation matrix:

```
private void Grid_MouseWheel(object sender, MouseWheelEventArgs e)
{
    var matTrans = grid2.RenderTransform as MatrixTransform;
    var pos1 = e.GetPosition(grid1);

    var scale = e.Delta > 0 ? 1.1 : 1 / 1.1;

    var mat = matTrans.Matrix;
    mat.ScaleAt(scale, scale, pos1.X, pos1.Y);
    matTrans.Matrix = mat;
    e.Handled = true;
}
```

Comment: I hope you don't mind, but I added an answer, based on your code, in the form of a `Behavior` for people trying to stick to the MVVM pattern.

Comment: @BradleyUffner I don't mind at all. A variety of good solutions helps SO as a whole and I'm more than happy with the way you mentioned my contribution ;)

Comment: This is a very nice simple solution. My question is, is there a way to change how the scaled contents are filtered (i.e using nearest neighbour)? I'm using this with a canvas which has a tiled image background, and despite trying `RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode` on the image, it has no effect, presumably because the render transform is applied afterwards.

Comment: Hi @Logix good question, but I don't know the answer. Maybe check whether https://stackoverflow.com/a/2913679/5265292 or one of the other answers specifically related to BitmapScalingMode helps. Otherwise you should probably open a new question

Answer (score 12):

I took @Grek40's code and converted it in to a `Behavior` for anyone trying to stick with the MVVM pattern.  If you up-vote this, please remember to also up-vote his answer too, as mine is based on his work.  It requires the [System.Windows.Interactivity.WPF](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Windows.Interactivity.WPF/) nuget package 
 (or some other framework) for the `Behavior` base-class.  You can apply this to any `UIElement`.  It will automatically add the `MatrixTransform` for you, so you don't have to do that in XAML (it will overwrite any existing transform).

```
public class ZoomOnMouseWheel : Behavior<FrameworkElement>
{
    public Key? ModifierKey { get; set; } = null;
    public TransformMode TranformMode { get; set; } = TransformMode.Render;

    private Transform _transform;

    protected override void OnAttached()
    {
        if (TranformMode == TransformMode.Render)
        {
            _transform = AssociatedObject.RenderTransform = new MatrixTransform();
        }
        else
        {
            _transform = AssociatedObject.LayoutTransform = new MatrixTransform();
        }

        AssociatedObject.MouseWheel += AssociatedObject_MouseWheel;
    }

    protected override void OnDetaching()
    {
        AssociatedObject.MouseWheel -= AssociatedObject_MouseWheel;
    }

    private void AssociatedObject_MouseWheel(object sender, MouseWheelEventArgs e)
    {
        if ((!ModifierKey.HasValue || !Keyboard.IsKeyDown(ModifierKey.Value)) && ModifierKey.HasValue)
        {
            return;
        }

        if (!(_transform is MatrixTransform transform))
        {
            return;
        }

        var pos1 = e.GetPosition(AssociatedObject);
        var scale = e.Delta > 0 ? 1.1 : 1 / 1.1;
        var mat = transform.Matrix;
        mat.ScaleAt(scale, scale, pos1.X, pos1.Y);
        transform.Matrix = mat;
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}

public enum TransformMode
{
    Layout,
    Render,
}
```

You can use it like this:

```
<Grid>
    <interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <behaviors:ZoomOnMouseWheel />
    </interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
    <!--Your grid content here-->
</Grid>
```

Don't forget the `xmlns`:

```
xmlns:interactivity="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
```

Comment: I've added the ability to only scroll when a modifier key, such as `LeftCtrl` is held down through the `ModifierKey` property, and the ability to control if the transform is done as a `RenderTranform` or a `LayoutTransform` through the `TransformMode` property.  It defaults to `RenderTransform`, but if you place the element with the `Behavior` inside a scrollviewer, and set it to `LayoutTransform`, you can get scrollbars when you zoom in.